# Ng-class if scope value equals attribute value of element clicked

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I write a ng-class function that adds the class "active" only if the scope value of "selectedFilter" == the value of the "type" attribute?

**HTML:**

```
<li ng-click="selectFilter($event)" ng-class="{'active': selectedFilter == $element.type}" type="portfolio">PORTFOLIO</li>
```

**Directive function:**

```
link: function(scope, el, attr) {
        scope.selectFilter = function(filterChosen){
            var selectedFilterValue =  filterChosen.target.attributes.type.value;
            scope.selectedFilter = selectedFilterValue;
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there's a great way to pass DOM context to a function on your scope without access to `$event` like ng-click has. You could alternatively forgo using ng-class at all and just assign the class manually by accessing element inside your ng-click function.

something like this:

```js
 for (var i = 0; i < element[0].children.length; i++) {
      if (element[0].children[i].type == scope.selectedFilter) {
        element[0].children[i].className = 'active'
      } else {
        element[0].children[i].className = ''
      }
    }
```